# How do i get linebreaks between the numbers 1-5

Tags: tabularx

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Facilitators and barriers: Literature study (Source: own table)}
    \label{tab:facilitators_barriers_overview_chapter3}
    \footnotesize  
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} ll*{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} @{}}
    \toprule 
 \textbf{Layer} && \textbf{Facilitator} & \textbf{Barrier} \\
    \midrule\midrule
    Learning
        &   1 \linebreak 
            2 \linebreak 
            3 \linebreak 
            4 \linebreak 
            5 \linebreak 
        &   Willingness to learn \linebreak 
            Willingness to share information \linebreak
            Sufficient workshops and training \linebreak
            Unstressed work working environment \linebreak
            Stimulated to share information 
                &   Lack of willingness to learn \linebreak 
                    Lack of willingness to share information
                    Insufficient workshops, training \linebreak
                    Stressed working environment \linebreak
                    Not stimulated to share information \\  \midrule
    Culture
        &&   Support from higher management \linebreak
            Positive feedback from colleagues \linebreak
            Failures and mistakes are accepted \linebreak
            Comfortable to speak your mind freely \linebreak
            Colleagues accept each other
            &   Lack of support from higher management \linebreak
                Lack of positive feedback from colleagues \linebreak
                Failures and mistakes are not accepted \linebreak
                Uncomfortable to speak your mind freely \linebreak
                Colleagues do not accept each other\\  \midrule
    Social   
        &&   Sufficient collaboration within teams \linebreak 
            Reliability \linebreak
            Honesty and integrity  \linebreak 
            Trust   \linebreak 
            Social contact   
                    &   Insufficient collaboration within teams \linebreak 
                    Insufficient reliability \linebreak 
                    Lack of honesty and integrity  \linebreak 
                    Lack of trust \linebreak 
                    Lack of social contact   \\  \midrule
    Technology 
        &&   Fast and efficient \linebreak 
            Reliable \linebreak
            Easy to use \linebreak
            Clear overview of systems that work consistent \linebreak
            Systems interconnect with each other
                &   Slow and inefficient \linebreak 
                    Unreliable \linebreak
                    Difficult to use \linebreak
                    Unclear overview of systems that work consistent \linebreak
                    Systems do not interconnect with each other \\  \midrule
    Process   
        &&   Clear and well understood \linebreak 
            Guidelines of the process are well documented  \linebreak
            Training is provided how to execute the process \linebreak
            Flexible \linebreak
            Clear outcome and desired results 
                &   Unclear or not well understood \linebreak
                    Guidelines of the process are not well documented \linebreak
                    Insufficient training on the process \linebreak
                    Inflexible \linebreak
                    Unclear outcome and undesired results \\ \midrule
    Infrastructure  
        &&   Pleasant physical working space  \linebreak
            Open door policy \linebreak
            Pleasant geographical distances  \linebreak
            Training facilities and meeting rooms available \linebreak
            Clean facilities
                &   Physical working space is unpleasant \linebreak
                    No open door policy \linebreak
                    Unpleasant geographical distances \linebreak
                    Lack of training facilities or meeting rooms \linebreak 
                    Unclean facilities \\  
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: `l` columns never break, try using `p{...}` instead

Comment: Do the numbers in the 2nd column corrrelate with the contents of the 3rd and 4th column?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use line breaks in standard columns  (`l,c`or `r`). You need a fixed width column for that. However, you can use  `\makecell` from the homonymous package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell, array}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Facilitators and barriers: Literature study (Source: own table)}
    \label{tab:facilitators_barriers_overview_chapter3}
    \footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} ll*{2}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} @{}}
    \toprule
 \textbf{Layer} && \textbf{Facilitator} & \textbf{Barrier} \\
    \midrule\midrule
    Learning
        &\makecell[l] {1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5}
        & Willingness to learn \linebreak
            Willingness to share information \linebreak
            Sufficient workshops and training \linebreak
            Unstressed work working environment \linebreak
            Stimulated to share information
                & Lack of willingness to learn \linebreak
                    Lack of willingness to share information
                    Insufficient workshops, training \linebreak
                    Stressed working environment \linebreak
                    Not stimulated to share information \\ \midrule
    Culture
        && Support from higher management \linebreak
            Positive feedback from colleagues \linebreak
            Failures and mistakes are accepted \linebreak
            Comfortable to speak your mind freely \linebreak
            Colleagues accept each other
            & Lack of support from higher management \linebreak
                Lack of positive feedback from colleagues \linebreak
                Failures and mistakes are not accepted \linebreak
                Uncomfortable to speak your mind freely \linebreak
                Colleagues do not accept each other\\ \midrule
    Social
        && Sufficient collaboration within teams \linebreak
            Reliability \linebreak
            Honesty and integrity \linebreak
            Trust \linebreak
            Social contact
                    & Insufficient collaboration within teams \linebreak
                    Insufficient reliability \linebreak
                    Lack of honesty and integrity \linebreak
                    Lack of trust \linebreak
                    Lack of social contact \\ \midrule
    Technology
        && Fast and efficient \linebreak
            Reliable \linebreak
            Easy to use \linebreak
            Clear overview of systems that work consistent \linebreak
            Systems interconnect with each other
                & Slow and inefficient \linebreak
                    Unreliable \linebreak
                    Difficult to use \linebreak
                    Unclear overview of systems that work consistent \linebreak
                    Systems do not interconnect with each other \\ \midrule
    Process
        && Clear and well understood \linebreak
            Guidelines of the process are well documented \linebreak
            Training is provided how to execute the process \linebreak
            Flexible \linebreak
            Clear outcome and desired results
                & Unclear or not well understood \linebreak
                    Guidelines of the process are not well documented \linebreak
                    Insufficient training on the process \linebreak
                    Inflexible \linebreak
                    Unclear outcome and undesired results \\ \midrule
    Infrastructure
        && Pleasant physical working space \linebreak
            Open door policy \linebreak
            Pleasant geographical distances \linebreak
            Training facilities and meeting rooms available \linebreak
            Clean facilities
                & Physical working space is unpleasant \linebreak
                    No open door policy \linebreak
                    Unpleasant geographical distances \linebreak
                    Lack of training facilities or meeting rooms \linebreak
                    Unclean facilities \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to put the content of the first cell in a `\parbox`:

```
Learning
    &   \parbox{0.5cm}{1 \linebreak 
        2 \linebreak 
        3 \linebreak 
        4 \linebreak 
        5 \linebreak}
```

I have made no other changes to your MWE. However, the way you have structured the cells, and defined column 2 and column 3, will give you challenges if you try to line up the the content of the cells in a row.

[image]